# JavaScript not working when is in separate file

Tags: javascript, html

I have code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 500) {
        $(".koncecki-web-design").addClass("konecki-scroll");
        $(".top-nav").addClass("show");
        $("#work").addClass("work-margin");
    } else {
        $(".koncecki-web-design").removeClass("konecki-scroll");
        $(".top-nav").removeClass("show");
        $("#work").removeClass("work-margin");
    }
    if (scroll >= 200) {
        $(".top-text").addClass("top-text-scroll");
    } else {
        $(".top-text").removeClass("top-text-scroll");
    }
});
```

I have this in my index file but i want to have in control.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/control.js"></script>
```

When i paste this code to control.js script does not work.

What could be wrong?

Thanks!
Silon

Comment: when you add the code to control.js, do you see any console log errors ?

Comment: you dont have jquery in the index..

Comment: Make sure jQuery is included before your `control.js`

Comment: did you also check whether document is ready? http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I don't have any errors and i have jquery link because this working when is in index :)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have jQuery included before control.js. So

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/control.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/control.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Check if you including control.js before jquery.js then it would not work move your jquery file to top.
2. DOM is not ready to be worked on so move all your code to `$(document).ready()`
3. Or include your control.js just before closing body tag, it will take care of above two points.